# How to set PATH environment variables in Cloude 9 (c9) IDE and/or run npm modules requiring Java

Tags: java, javascript, node.js, gruntjs, cloud9-ide

For various reasons (and because of a recent back injury), I needed to get an "ultra-light" laptop. I went with the recently best-selling [Samsung Chromebook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B009LL9VDG), and I can actually get quite a lot of real work done.

I ported one of my [projects (very alpha)](https://c9.io/somecallmechief/ojs) over to [Cloud9](http://c9.io), the service of which is outstanding (really, really good). Because c9 is effectively running NodeJs on NodeJs for each workspace you define: I can run all of my Node tasks; I can Grunt in c9; nearly anything I can do on a "full" OS, I can do in c9.

Except for Java dependent tasks. Specifically with Grunt, there are a few tasks I can't run because no environment variable for Java can be found:

```
JAVA_HOME is no set, but java is required by jsdoc to run.
```

Never-minding the grammar, it is possible to run jsdoc (or closure-compiler, etc) by opening c9's proper Terminal which:

```
somecallmechief@ojs:~/406658 (master) $ which java                                                                                                                                                            
    /usr/bin/java
```

knows all about Java. I can even export the path and run my Grunt tasks in the terminal--but only in this Terminal instance.

Given that Java is clearly part of my virtual workspace, is it possible to define the JAVA_HOME environment variable as a constant/persistent value? And if so, how?

Thanks for listening

- and no, `npm install java` is not the answer

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm getting this same error running on a mac, and have no problems working with jsDocs outside of grunt, or finding java in my path...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Cloud9 is tackling this themselves. [Based on their latest blog post](https://c9.io/site/blog/2013/03/the-changelog-of-march-stability-performance-features/), the former 'Console' is no more. Instead you get the Terminal right out of the box, and since it's a fully baked, fully configurable bash terminal--that's all you need.